# Drag & drop URL from address bar into folder = automagically convert + download

Tags: shortcuts, conversion, drag-and-drop, youtube-dl

How would I go about finding out how to drag & drop shortcut URL from browser address bar into folder to auto download / convert to audio mp3?

After dragging into folder, the output file would goto same folder (or music folder or wherever). It would work something like this:

[image: 8t9-514]

Comment: This functionality does not exist at this time in ANY of the major browsers.  If it does exist it would require a browser extension. It most definitely would not be a drag and drop function from the URL field (that universally creates a Internet shortcut to the website)

Comment: why would it have to be an extension in your opinion? you think a desktop app would not be able to retrieve internet shortcut data without proper access provided from extension?

Comment: Because no browser supports what you describe, since all browsers are based one one of three engines they all are similar (to those that use the same engine)